# Android: Restart Timer

Tags: java, android, eclipse, timer, timertask

I created a TimerTask with the following code:

```
    Screen_Timer_Task = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                    // Do my stuff

            }
    });

    }

    };
```

Then, I start that TimerTask with that:

```
    Screen_Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Screen_Timer_Task, 1, 1);
```

This is working fine. But after calling

```
    Screen_Timer.cancel();

    Screen_Timer.purge();
```

it will not restart with

```
    Screen_Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Screen_Timer_Task, 1, 1);
```

The app is just crashing!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void start_my_timer()
{

    Screen_Timer_Task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {


                runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                                // Do my stuff
                    }
                });

        }

    };

    Screen_Timer.schedule(Screen_Timer_Task, 1, 1);

}
```

Comment: Create new `Timer` every time

Comment: Yes. That was the solution. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Is not ok, the timer is restarted but the Thread will be still alive

Answer (score 1):

"The task may be run once " from docs [timerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)

You must create `TimerTask` object again if you want to use it.

Also make `Timer` once again because `cancel()`:
"Cancels the Timer and all scheduled tasks. If there is a currently running task it is not affected. No more tasks may be scheduled on this Timer. Subsequent calls do nothing."

Comment: No, it didn't work. I put this in a public void function and call it, but at the second time, the app is crashing.

Comment: So Show LogCat which you got

Comment: I send the application to my device via LAN connection, so I have no LogCat.

Comment: So show how you are now creating your TimerTask again every time